# Why would a slower clock rate 20 v 40 MHz be better at driving an LED matrix

Tags: clock, led, rate

I'm looking into creating a custom shield for driving an LED matrix, looking at clock speeds which can drive the matrix based off this thread(http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26130&start=0) it seems that >50MHz is unable to drive the matrix. How is this possible? I thought a fast clock rate would be better at driving an LED matrix...

I'm looking at using at ATMega328-pu which has a clock speed of 20MHz.

Comment: probably it's a good idea to check the datasheet first...

Comment: There is no public data sheet for this LED matrix